# How to config Sails/Node App with Apache/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, apache

First of all, this is for dev purposes only. On my Mac I've got Apache running with Passenger which serve many Rails/Ruby App. An example of an Apach config for Rails would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.lc
    ServerAlias www.example.lc
    RailsEnv development
    PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
    PassengerRuby /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/wrappers/ruby
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/my/app/public"
    ErrorLog "/path/to/my/app/log"
    CustomLog "/path/to/my/app/log" common
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
        <Directory "/path/to/my/app/public">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And on my host file I'd have `192.168.0.1    www.example.lc` and that would work fine.

I'd like to do the same for a Node App based off Sails. I've tried the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.lc
    ServerAlias www.example.lc
    NODE_ENV development
    PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
    PassengerNodejs /usr/bin/node
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/my/app/public"
    ErrorLog "/path/to/my/app/log"
    CustomLog "path/to/my/app/log" common
    ServerAdmin me@example.com
        <Directory "/path/to/my/app/public">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But that doesn't work. Nor it shows any error on the log file. Any ideas?

Please note that I've also tried `PassengerNodejs /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/node` which is the path I get when I do `which node`. That didn't work either.